# Configured jenkins in ec2 ubantu but unable to access it via ec2 public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

did the follwing

1. configured jenkins in my ec2
2. sudo systemctl status jenkins shows that jenkins is runing
3. added an inbound rule for ec2 instance to access public IP and port 8080 anywhere

earlier was able to access jankins dashboard on publicDNS:8080 but when ever i restart the instance ,

and retry accessing the dashboard through my browser on same ip Address and port ,

> PublicDNS took too long to respond.

getting this message and unable to access jenkins dashboard.

changed and added the inbound rule again , was expecting to access jenkins dashboard but was unable to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the primary reason for this is the way chrome or other browsers call a URL
even if you specify http method , they tend to periodically redirect your request to an https menthod for ip, other pages of the ip .

an easy work around for this is use the incognito mode of the browser.

another issue might be incase you have configured your ec2 inbound rule for "My IP" .

in this case , make sure that you system's public IP is static.